# How many sockets are needed per connection?

Tags: c++, c, winsock, winsock2

Say we have a server program with socket sa and new_socket. The tutorial I'm using takes socket sa and new_socket, and two structures of `sockaddr_in` named `server` and `client`; then binds the socket to an IP address:port, then calls `listen()` function. When `listen` returns, the program calls

```
new_socket = accept(sa, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &length);
```

My question is, lets say there are 3 people connecting...
Do I need to have 3 different structs and 3 different new_sockets for each `accept` function, say if i want my server to serve 3 different clients connecting to it?

Also, why do we need a new_socket for `accept`? Why is there two different sockets 1 for `bind` and 1 for `accept`? Shouldn't socket operations be performed on the `bind`ed one?

I'm trying to implement a class for sockets to make it easier on me, and as a good way to practice my oop skills....

Comment: You typically have one socket that listens for incoming connections, and one socket per client.

Answer (score 2):

You need one socket for the server in general. This socket is where you set the port that the server is listening on, and call `accept()` to wait for incoming connections.

In addition, you need a socket for each client connection. This is a new socket that is returned by `accept()`. This is necessary because a server can handle multiple clients. If you used one socket for everything, there would be no way to tell which client was sending you a message, or indicate which client to send a reply to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So lets say if im making a server, but i dont know how many people are going to connect to it. How would my program know how many sockets to create based on the number of clients connecting to it? Would i have an array of sockets declare with new or malloc, and then i would add a socket everytime listen unblocks? Also, in the tutorial, the server exits once you connect to it. If i want to keep the server alive, which winsock functions will I have to loop (accept and listen perhaps?)

Comment: You do listen once, and accept returns once per connection.  Store the sockets in any kind of container.  You will need to use select() to detect which socket (including your accept socket) has a packet to be processed.

Comment: Yes, you use an array. Whenever `accept()` returns, you add the new socket to the array. If the array fills up, you can grow it with `realloc()` to handle more clients. You only need to call `listen()` once, you then call `accept()` in the main loop to get new connections.

Comment: I think your questions are getting beyond the type that are appropriate for SO. This is not a tutorial and discussion site, you need to read programming tutorials or talk to your instructor for what you want.